How to make blurry toolbar like telegram in android
Make toolbar blur with low opacity color.
in short i want draw edge to edge with translucent navigation bar with dark and light themes but with blur effect And the reflection of the views behind the toolbar should be visible .
Something like this toolbar in telegram app


You can achieve a blurry toolbar depending on a simple library like: RealtimeBlurView
Here is an XML layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rl_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_bg_section">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_10dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_backarrow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/back_arrow_margin"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
                    android:theme="@style/ImageRippleEffect"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/notification_icon"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/notification_icon"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/notification_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_38dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_38dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_3dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    style="@style/labelSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
                    android:text="Tilte"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/notification_icon"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar_backarrow"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/notification_icon" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/notification_icon"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/_2dp"
                    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabPadding="@dimen/padding_small"
                    app:tabRippleColor="@null"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTradingTabTextAppearance">

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Tab1" />

                    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Tab2" />
                </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="@dimen/margin_large">


                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:id="@+id/clTDS"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                        <com.mantasolutions.app.utils.customUi.justifyView.JustifiedTextView
                            android:id="@+id/tdsLabel1"
                            style="@style/paragraphXSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingTop="110dp"
                            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum_is_simply_dummy_text"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.github.mmin18.widget.RealtimeBlurView
            android:id="@+id/blurView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/toolbar"
            app:realtimeBlurRadius="15dp"
            app:realtimeOverlayColor="@color/transparent_black" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


This layout features:

A Toolbar at the top.
A TabLayout below the toolbar with two tabs.
A NestedScrollView for the main content.
A RealtimeBlurView positioned over the toolbar, providing a dynamic blur effect.

The result:


